# invoke property getter in angular material

Tags: javascript, angular-material, getter

I cant get values from check box in a table of angular material.
I try many options
get, JSON.stringify(), class with get, OnChanges and nothing work!

this is the message in console "in this.selection":

invoke property getter

and the console appers with () parentesis... when i try to get this.
I attach a img

[image]

this is the table with checkbox example in angular material

https://stackblitz.com/angular/krkppqljojv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-selection-example.ts

Only I what the check box selected, but alwais I have the las selecction, not the actual

I share, look

```
table... init

<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th
      mat-header-cell
      *matHeaderCellDef
    >
      <mat-checkbox
        (change)="$event ? this.masterToggle() : null"
        [checked]="this.selection.hasValue() && this.isAllSelected()"
        [indeterminate]="this.selection.hasValue() && !this.isAllSelected()"
        [aria-label]="this.checkboxLabel()"
        (click)="this.getSelect(selection);"
      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td
      mat-cell
      *matCellDef="let row"
    >
      <mat-checkbox
        (change)="$event ? this.selection.toggle(row) : null"
        [checked]="this.selection.isSelected(row)"
        [aria-label]="this.checkboxLabel(row)"
        (click)="this.getSelect(row);"
      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>



table... end
```

In this console is my problem, some ideas?

```
  getSelect(event: any) {
    console.log(this.selection); // {etc: {...}, selected: (...), _etc:}
    console.log(this.selection.selected); // []
    // this.journeysSelected.emit(this.selection);
  }
```

as you can see, when console log is this.selection, the property selected have a properties but with (...) and then I click and show the array with values.

buet when I console log this.selection.selected the is [] empty array.

Please don't put me (-1)   =(   be mercy

Answer (score 1):

remove the click event in tag

```
<!--select-->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th
      mat-header-cell
      *matHeaderCellDef
    >
      <mat-checkbox
        (change)="$event ? this.masterToggle() : null"
        [checked]="this.selection.hasValue() && this.isAllSelected()"
        [indeterminate]="this.selection.hasValue() && !this.isAllSelected()"
        [aria-label]="this.checkboxLabel()"

      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td
      mat-cell
      *matCellDef="let row"
    >
      <mat-checkbox
        (change)="$event ? this.selection.toggle(row) : null"
        [checked]="this.selection.isSelected(row)"
        [aria-label]="this.checkboxLabel(row)"

      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

make a subscription:

```
export class JourneyTableComponent implements OnInit {

serv: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>(); // declare the Subject


ngOnInit() {
    this.getValue().pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(), // important because detectec are many changes
      map(value => this.selectedJourneys = value),
    ).subscribe(value => console.log(this.selectedJourneys)); // made things
}

getValue(): Observable<any> {
    return this.serv.asObservable();
}

setValue(newValue): void {
    this.serv.next(newValue);
}


isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    this.setValue(this.selection.selected); // set value when you click
    const numRows = this.dataSource.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }


... more code
}
```

Enjoy